# GORM get domain object list by property

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I'm trying to get a list of domain objects back, but only those that the user is allowed to see. This is based on what granted role that user has from spring security.

What I'd like to be able to do in my controller is something along the lines of

```
[reportInstanceList: Report.list(params).sort{it.name}]
```

but only get the reports where

```
Report.role = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()
```

I have the Spring security stuff in another service class, but for simplicity's sake, its inline here.

Is there a way to direct GORM to only pull the records where the roles match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
def reports = Report.createCriteria().list( params ) {
    'in'( "role", SpringSecurityUtils.principalAuthorities )
}
[ reportInstanceList: reports, totalCount: reports.totalCount ]
```

Should work...

Answer (score 0):

This is what [dynamic finders](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#finders) are for. You can use the [`findAllBy`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html) finder to get all the objects with an attribute.

```
Report.findAllByRoleInList(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities())
```

You can also sort at the db level by passing a map of params.

```
Report.findAllByRoleInList(roles, [sort: 'name'])
```